# Entropy in the Klimontovich Picture of Kinetic Theory

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy, simulations, kinetic-theory

In the Klimontovich picture of kinetic theory, a classical $N$-body system is fully specified by the phase-space distribution
$$
\rho(\vec X,t) = \sum_{i=1}^N\delta[\vec X-\vec X_i(t)]
,
$$
where $\vec X_i=(\vec q_i,\vec p_i)$ is the phase-space coordinate of particle $i$, and $\delta$ is the Dirac delta distribution. This distribution can be accurately approximated by certain computer simulation methods, e.g., molecular dynamics. Suppose I wanted to compute the entropy of a particular configuration obtained by such a simulation. My natural inclincation is to compute $$S = -k_B\left<\ln\rho\right>$$ with the angle brackets denoting
$$
\left<A(\vec X)\right> = \frac{\int A(\vec X) \rho\, d\vec X}{\int \rho \,d\vec X}
= \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N A(\vec X_i)
,
$$
i.e., just the sample mean.

For most observables, such a computation makes perfectly good sense and is simple to do given the output of an $N$-body simulation. But naively going through the same motions with $A=\ln\rho$ as the observable leads to strange attempts to take the logarithm of Dirac deltas. On paper, I have trouble making sense of this, much less the matter of computing it from simulation data.

My experience has taught me these kinds of problems are a sign that I have missed something at the big-picture scale. Is the Klimontovich distribution incompatible with the usual notion of entropy in statistical mechanics? If so, what is the disconnect? Essentially, **does it make sense to compute the entropy of a phase-space configuration in isolation?**

Comment: What if the particles have finite size, does this take care of the problem?

Comment: I don't believe so. The deltas represent that particles have sure (non-random) coordinates and momenta, not that they are point particles. That is, even a system of hard spheres may be characterized by the motion of each particles' center.